# Efficient way of emulating LIMIT (FETCH), OFFSET in Progress OpenEdge 10.1B SQL using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2000, openedge

I want to be able to use the equivalent of MySQL's LIMIT, OFFSET in Progress OpenEdge 10.1b.

Whilst the FETCH/OFFSET commands are available as of Progress OpenEdge 11, unfortunately version 10.1B does not have them, therefore it is difficult to produce paged recordsets (e.g. Records 1-10, 11-20, 21-30 etc.).

ROW_NUMBER is also not supported by 10.1b. Seems that it is pretty much the same functionality as was found in SQL Server 2000.

If searching always in the order of the primary key id (pkid), this could be achieved by using "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table ORDER BY pkid ASC", then identifying the last pkid and finding the next set with "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table WHERE pkid>last_pkid ORDER BY pkid ASC"; this, however only works when sorting by the pkid.

My solution to this was to write a PHP function where I could pass the limit and offset and then return only the results where the row number was between my those defined values. I use TOP to return no more than the sum of the limit and offset.

```
function limit_query($sql, $limit=NULL, $offset=0)
    {
        $out      = array();
        if ($limit!=NULL) {
            $sql=str_replace_first("SELECT", "SELECT TOP ".($limit+$offset), $sql);
        }
        $query = $db->query($sql); //$db is my DB wrapper class
        $i=0;
        while ($row = $this->fetch($query)) {
            if ($i>=$offset) { //only add to return array if greater than offset
                $out[] = $row;
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $db->free_result($query);
        return $out;
    }
```

This works well on small recordsets or on the first few pages of results, but if the total results are in the thousands, if you want to see results on page 20, 100 or 300, it is very slow and inefficient (Page one is querying only the first 10 results, page 2 the first 20 but page 100 will query the first 1000).

Whilst in most cases, the user will probably not venture past page 2 or 3, so the lack of efficiency isn't perhaps a major issue, I do wonder if there is a more efficient way of emulating this functionality.

Sadly, upgrading to a newer version of Progress, or a superior database such as MySQL is not an option, as the db is provided by third-party software.

Can anyone suggest alternative, more efficient methods?

Comment: What was the exact reason the vendor gave for not being able to upgrade? 10.1B is ancient and SQL support has been improved greatly since then. fwiw Progress is not SQL based and SQL is more of a bolt on in those ancient versions.

Comment: I'm not sure the exact reason. I know they plan to upgrade within the next few months. They do say they have to upgrade all clients at once and I know they have a LOT of clients all over the world so it's probably due to the logistics of it that they haven't done so yet. Also, as the software itself works fine, I guess upgrading has not been a priority.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand the question, so here's an attempt to give you an answer:
You probably won't be able to do what you want with a single hit to the db. Just by sorting records / adding functions you probably won't achieve the paging functionality you are trying to get. As far as I know, Progress won't number the rows, unless, as you said, you're sorting by some crescent pkid.
My suggestion to you would be a procedure to run in the back end to create the query with a batch size same as the page (in your case 10), and use a loop to get the next batch until you get the ones you need. Look into batching datasets or use an open query using MAX-ROWS.
Hope it helps, or at least gives you an idea to get this. I actually like your PHP implementation, it seems like a good workaround, not ugly to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install an upgraded version of Progress, convert your database(s) and recompile the code against the new version.  Normally your support through your vendor would provide you with the latest version of Progress (Openedge) and wouldn't be a huge issue. Going from version 10 to 11 shouldn't cause any compile issues and give you all of the SQL benefits of the newer version.

Honestly your comment about MySql being superior is a little confusing, but that's a discussion for another day. ;D

Best regards!